# Why does my house have noodles/pasta/spaghetti on it?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

My house in [Kingdom of Loathing](http://www.kingdomofloathing.com/static.php?id=whatiskol) looks weird. What happened? What’s the purpose of this? There’s spaghetti all over it…

Compare it with [the housing shown here](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Resting#Housing).

[image]

Comment: KoL. wow that still runs? Been a long time.

Comment: @Ids it even shows up in the [community promo ads](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8047/177) from time to time.

Comment: I love that you mistook them for noodles.  I can't unsee that now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This means someone teepee'd your house with [toilet paper](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Roll_of_toilet_paper).

If you rest at your housing structure, you will automatically rid your house of toilet paper, and gain 1 Strongness.

However, if you let others continually pelt your housing structure without cleaning up, you end up salvaging some of the toilet paper rolls for use, so you can take revenge on those who dared to tarnish your home.